# Why isn't that conditional expectation calculated directly?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I mean

```
Expectation[y \[Conditioned]  x/y == t, {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[2], 
y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[3]}]
```

returns the input in 13.2 on Windows 10. That expectation can be calculated as follows.

```
Expectation[y \[Conditioned]  x/y <= t + eps && x/y >= t - eps, 
{x \[Distributed]  ExponentialDistribution[2],  y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[3]}]
```

> `Piecewise[{{(2*(3 + eps + t))/(9 + 6*eps + 6*t),  eps >= t && eps > 0 && eps + t > 0},  {(6 + 4*t)/(-4*eps^2 + (3 + 2*t)^2), eps < t && eps > 0}}, 0]`

```
Limit[%, eps -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

> `Piecewise[{{2/(3 + 2*t), t >= 0}}, 0]`

I am not able to trace the command under consideration to find out the reason. It would be kind of more experienced users to explain such a behavior.

Comment: The same issue with `Expectation[
 y \[Conditioned] 
  x + y == t, {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[2], 
  y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[3]}]` and `Expectation[
 y \[Conditioned] 
  x * y == t, {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[2], 
  y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[3]}]`

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**  Modified to use `\[Conditioned]`.

This does not answer why the commands are simply returned.  However, here are two approaches to obtain the conditional mean without needing to resort to taking limits.

```
(* Joint distribution of y and r = x/y *)
dist = TransformedDistribution[{y, x/y},
  {x, y} \[Distributed] ProductDistribution[ExponentialDistribution[2], 
  ExponentialDistribution[3]]];

(* Joint pdf of y and r = x/y *)
pdfyr = FullSimplify[PDF[dist, {y, r}], Assumptions -> {y > 0, r > 0}]
(* 6 E^-((3 + 2 r) y) y *)

dist2 = ProbabilityDistribution[pdfyr, {y, 0, ∞}, {r, 0, ∞}]
Expectation[y \[Conditioned] r == r0, {y, r} \[Distributed] dist2,
  Assumptions -> r0 > 0]    
(* (* 2/(3 + 2 r0) *)
```

Here is more of a brute force way:

```
(* Marginal pdf of r = x/y *)
pdfr = FullSimplify[PDF[MarginalDistribution[dist, 2], r], Assumptions -> r > 0]
(* 6/(3 + 2 r)^2 *)

(* Conditional density of y given r *)
pdfyGivenr = pdfyr/pdfr
(* E^-((3 + 2 r) y) (3 + 2 r)^2 y *)

(* Conditional mean of y given r *)
mean = Integrate[y pdfyGivenr, {y, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> r > 0]
(* 2/(3 + 2 r) *)
```

Comment: How do you explain the difference in  `Expectation[
 y \[Conditioned] 
  x + y == 1, {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[2], 
  y \[Distributed] ExponentiaDistribution[3]}]` which returns the input and `Expectation[
 y \[Conditioned] 
  x + y == 1, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 2], 
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[1, 3]}]` which performs `1`? TIA.

Comment: I think that's a question you'll need to ask Wolfram, Inc.  If you use `dist = TransformedDistribution[{y, x + y}, {x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[2], y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[3]}]; pdf = FullSimplify[PDF[dist, {y, z}], Assumptions -> 0 < y < z]; dist2 = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf, {z, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y, 0, z}]; Expectation[y \[Conditioned] z == 1, {y, z} \[Distributed] dist2]`, then that works with the conditional expectation.

Comment: +1. It's my vote.